# Python Windows open permission denied as adminstrator

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, uac

I have simple python code on Windows that reads/writes a log file that I don't want standard users to have write access, so I have made the log files restricted to Adminstrator write privileges.

```
import os
l = open('filename.log', 'w')
```

I can't figure out how to debug it without running into a permission denied error. Debugging in PyCharm and even though starting PyCharm as admin, I get the error.

I can, however, run a python shell as admin and open/write my log file without error.

How can I run PyCharm to debug without getting the error?

Comment: why not either change the permissions during debugging or run your debugger with administrative permissions ?

Comment: I'm already running the debugger with administrative permissions, but it still gives an error and I want to debug as different users to make sure permission levels work.

Comment: To test this I installed PyCharm 4.5 community edition in Windows 7. I cannot confirm that a problem exists. When I run the IDE elevated via "run as administrator", the child python.exe process, which it executes to run and debug scripts, is also elevated. That's to be expected since a child process defaults to inheriting a copy of the parent's access token.

Comment: You can further test this by opening a python console from with PyCharm and entering the simple code above (ensure the file is admin-write only).

Comment: @mjpsr11, I examined the process token using sysinternals [accesschk](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922.aspx) to determine that the administrators group is enabled, all administrator privileges are available, and the token integrity label is high, i.e. the child process is elevated with full administrator access. To check this yourself use `accesschk -pv -f [pid]`. Without elevation the administrators group will be disabled or missing, only basic privileges will be available, and the integrity will be medium.

Answer (score 0):

After confirming that the PyCharm process is running with administrators group using accesschk as recommended by eryksun, the code is now executing without the error.